# How to get the line number which raised an exception in current frame exclude subframe which is actually raised it?

Tags: python, exception

> Background:when i call many library function, one of them raised an
> exception, i want to know which call in my code raised it, but the
> call chain is very deep, it's hard to find which line, in my code,
> raised the exception.

How to get the line number which raised an exception in the frame main(), when i call `do_something1()`, it called a very deeply subframe and caused an exception, this make me hard to find which line raised the exception in the frame `main()` when i print the error information.

```py
def do_somethingN():

    raise Exception("some error happened")


def do_something1():
    # do_something1 call do_something2, do_something2 call do_something3 ...
    do_somethingN()

def main():
    import traceback
    try:
        do_something1()
    except Exception as e:
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        print(tb)

main()
```

Comment: I don't know which frame raised the exception, and I can't write `raise Exception("example")` in the inner of library function.

Comment: Good advice, thanks!